# MultiThreading and Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

suggest me any real time situations in which i'm supposed to create multiple threads,and then introduce a deadlock situation.this is kind of a project!!! can u ppl help to make the application more interestin with some real time situation

Comment: you need to comeup with ideas yourself as this is your assignment.

Comment: By "real-time" do you mean that the homework assignment is about to be handed in as you're asking this question on SO?

Answer (score 5):

think philosophers, golden forks and a big bowl of spaghetti

Comment: I heard about them dining, but golden forks?!? Philosophers have moved up in the world

Comment: Is this a real time example or text book example :)

Comment: It was a long time ago, maybe I invented the golden forks

Answer (score 2):

This will cause a deadlock:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  final Object object1 = new Object();
  final Object object2 = new Object();

  Thread thread1 = new Thread(
    new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run() 
      {    
        try 
        {    
          //**** Lock on object1 first ****
          synchronized(object1) 
          {    
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //**** Lock on object2 second ****
            synchronized(object2) 
            {
              System.out.println("Should never get here.");
            }
          }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {    
          System.out.println("Thread interupted.");
        }
      }
    }
  );

  Thread thread2 = new Thread(
    new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run() 
      {
        try 
        {
          //**** Lock on object2 first ****
          synchronized(object2) 
          {    
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //**** Lock on object1 second ****
            synchronized(object1) 
            {
              System.out.println("Should never get here.");
            }
          }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
          System.out.println("Thread interupted.");
        }
      }
    }
  );

  thread1.start();
  thread2.start();
}
```

Basically you've got 2 threads competing for locks on the same objects.  Thread 1 gets the lock on `object1` while thread 2 gets a lock on `object2`, each then tries to get a lock on the other object and you've got a deadlock because another thread already has the lock.

Comment: Sleep does not guarantee deadlock IMO.

Comment: The `sleep` is there to give each thread time to get their first locks (on `object1` and `object2` respectively) before trying to get their second locks (on `object2` and `object1` respectively).  While it's possible that `thread2` hasn't got its lock within a 1000ms, it's unlikely.  Ultimately the `sleep` is there as a simple mechanism to make the deadlock happen but isn't the cause of the deadlock itself, the cause is the competing locks.

Comment: Thank you very much. If there is a certain question like write a program which will always end up in a deadlock then I have to think of some other way, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the producer-consumer algorithm to demonstrate multi-threading.

Report generator
Scenario would be, data per report is inserted into a queue for further processing by one service (the producer). The report processor service (the consumer) takes data for a report from the queue and processes them one report at a time. There can be 5 diferent instances of report processor service. All of them consume reports from a single queue (this is where you might need to introduce locks on the queue, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can also deadlock with a fixed size thread pool:

```
final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
exec.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Future<?> f = exec.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        });
        try { f.get(); } catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
});
```